# Get all files in the -C specified folder of tar

Tags: c, tar

I've been looking around and testing, and I feel that there's no solution, but I want to ask before giving up.

I'm creating tar files through C, which results in this instruction at some point:

```
execlp("tar", "tar", "czf", file_folder_out, "-C", file_folder_in, "./*", NULL);
```

Which is equivalent in terminal to

```
tar -czf /home/Skywalker/.tmp/test.tar.gz -C /home/Skywalker/.tmp/pack ./*
```

Is there a way to get all files from the -C folder without specifing them manually (reading them with readdir), and using those as root (no adding the pack folder or the . folder in as the root folder)? I tried a lot of combinations, and didn't work.

Comment: cd /home/Skywalker/.tmp/pack && tar -czf /home....tar.gz .

Comment: I said I'm doing it in a C program. I can see a lot of ways of doing it in shell, but I would like to just exec tar, and avoid exec a shell.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see any mention of the need to avoid a shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intent is that `./*` is a glob pattern, specifying all files in the current directory (that do not begin with a `.`). It does not work without a shell, as it is expanded by the shell to a list of all files in the current directory.

I hope that you realize the command will not archive *all* the files in the directory specified by `file_folder_in`, since the `./*` expands to the list of files *in the current directory*. It tries to archive files and subdirectories in `file_folder_in` that match file or directory names in the current directory (that do not start with a `.`).

(By convention, `*` (and the equivalent `./*`) do not match files that begin with a dot.)

I highly suspect you intend to execute

```
execlp("tar", "tar", "czf", file_folder_out, "-C", file_folder_in, ".", NULL);
```

instead, which tells `tar` to archive all files and subdirectories in `file_folder_in` directory.

The above *does* include files that start with `.`, too. If you wish to avoid that use

```
execlp("tar", "tar", "czf", file_folder_out, "-C", file_folder_in, "--exclude", ".[^/]*", ".", NULL);
```

which tells `tar` to exclude files and directories that begin with a `.` (but are not just `./`, which specifies the current directory). I believe the exclude support is common to all `tar` variants (I know it should work with both GNU tar and FreeBSD tar, but am not sure about any others), so it *should* work regardless of the tar variant -- but I'd personally not exclude the dot-files, for completeness and portability reasons.

Questions?

Comment: I was trying combination with `*`, so it failed every time, so thanks for the answer. Just to make sure: both instructions give the same result. I get (opening with a file extractor) ./(folders in file_folder_in) for both cases. It doesn't seem that it should be like this.

Comment: @markmb: If you have subdirectory or file `file_folder_in/.secret`, first one includes it, second one does not. In both cases the stored paths begin with `./`. If the `./` prefix bothers you, you need to use `execlp("tar", "tar", "czf", file_folder_out, "-C", file_folder_dir, file_folder_name, NULL)` or `execlp("tar", "tar", "czf", file_folder_out, "-C", file_folder_dir, "--exclude", ".*", file_folder_name, NULL)` instead, where `file_folder_dir` contains the directory part of `file_folder_in`, i.e. all but last component, and `file_folder_name` the last component (`basename(file_folder_in)`).